# proxy settings in firefox via bash do not work

Tags: firefox, proxy

pretty straightforward :

I have got:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

I want to set a proxy in firefox  through bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

IP="1.2.3.4"
PORT="2200"

grep -v "network.proxy.\(http\|http_port\|type\)" prefs.js  > temp && mv temp prefs.js

echo "user_pref(\"network.proxy.http\", \"$IP\")" >> prefs.js 
echo "user_pref(\"network.proxy.http_port\", $PORT)" >> prefs.js
echo "user_pref(\"network.proxy.type\", 1)" >> prefs.js
```

prefs.js is modified accordingly but firefox does not set the proxy. See the image included.

[image]

I have got the exact same issue, using this code:

```
cat <<EOT >> prefs.js
user_pref("network.proxy.http", $IP);
user_pref("network.proxy.http_port", $PORT);
user_pref("network.proxy.type", 1);
EOT
```

thank you very much folks !!

Comment: with cat <<EOT, should be "$IP" instead of $IP, sorry for that typo

Answer (score 0):

actually I found a solution, before setting the proxy, I test it. 
see this code:

```
result=`HEAD -d -p http://$IP:$PORT -t 20 www.any_url.com HTTP/1.1`
if [ "$result" = "200 OK" ]; then
    [do whatever you want...]
    break;
else
    [do something else ...]
fi

done;
```

see http://snipplr.com/view/17899/http-proxy-checker/

This way there is no need to set and unset proxy over and over again; it 's lot faster as well.